# Why does this simple method not work?

Tags: c#

It must be simple, but i can't seem to find the explanation. Why does the following generates these errors:

1. Unreachable code detected  (on result++)
2. WindowsFormsApplication1.Form1.GetResult(int, int): not all code paths return a value

   ```
   private int GetResult(int start, int end)
   {
       for (int result = start; result < end; result++)
       {
           return result;
       } 
   }
   ```

Anyone who could please help me out? Thnx in advance :)

**EDIT:**
First of all, thanks for the many (fast) replys. Stupid of mine...but i didn't see it.

And sorry, i needed to be a little more precise of what it is i wanted to accieve..
I need a method that adds 1 to a value (result) starting from the given start value (int start) untill it reaches another value (int end).
So it might also add directly to start integer if I’m not mistaking. And return that value?

Comment: I have a another question. What do u want to do? This code is very weird o0

Comment: After fixing, this could be optimised to `private int GetResult(int start, int end){return start;}`. Which is pointless, leading some of us to suspect it isn't what you actually want.

Comment: @John Hanna you are right and then no need to call the function. He can use just start as a result instead of calling the method :)

Comment: My guess is that he wants to return a sequence of numbers.

Comment: (In response to your edit) Assuming start < end, adding one to `start` until `start == end`, then returning `start`, is equivalent to just returning `end` -- only more wasteful. Remember that (unless you pass in a mutable object, or modify fields) anything you don't `return` is forgotten when the method completes.

Comment: @Erikjansen, You may start a new thread/question for your problem, rather than extending the current question. Also you may clarify what exactly you need ? do you need a list of numbers in sequence from Start to End ?

Comment: @Erikjansen - Have a look at my post here on how to return a sequence of numbers from your method, and consume them http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12174259/why-does-this-simple-method-not-work/12174296#12174296

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What a clever compiler!

```
for (int result = start; result < end; result++)
{
    return result;
}
```

... is equivalent to:

```
int result = start;
while(result < end) {
  return result;
  result++;
}
```

If start >= end as we go into this code, the content of the while loop will never run. In that case, the program flow won't hit a `return` statement: **Not all code paths return a value**.

If start < end as we enter the function, the program flow will go into the loop, hit the `return` statement, and the method will return. It can't hit the `result++` statement. **Unreachable code detected**.

---

In response to your edit:

```
public int getResult(int start, int end) {
   int result = start;
   while(result < end) {
       result++;
   }
   return result;
}
```

... does what you describe. However it's a wasteful way to get that result. If start=0 and end=1000000, the program will loop a million times.

You'd get exactly same result more efficiently with:

```
public int getResult(int start, int end) {
   if(end > start) {
      return end;
   } else {
      return start;
   }
}
```

Or even:

```
public int getResult(int start, int end) {
   return Math.Max(start,end);
}
```

(Although it's still not clear what you want the result to be if `start > end`)

Answer (score 11):

Because your method is returning an `int` type, and the compiler can't determine whether you will get inside the loop.

What if the `result` is greater than or equal to `end`, in that case, the statement inside the loop will not execute and hence you get the error.

From [MSDN - For Loop](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ch45axte%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)

> Because the test of a conditional expression occurs before the
>   execution of the loop, a for statement executes zero or more times.

This gives you the reason behind the error "not all code path returns a value", because if the for loop executes `0` times then the method will not return anything

For warning "Unreachable code detected", the reason is that your update expression `result++` executes after the execution of the for block. Since your for block contains `return` statement, you will never reach your update expression

Answer (score 4):

There are two different cases at the beginning of the method:

- Case `start < end`: You always return `result` immediately in the
  first loop run. Therefore `result` is never going to be incremented.
- Case `start >= end`: You never enter the loop, therefore you'd need
  another `return` statement outside of it.

Answer (score 4):

It is obvious that `result++` is unreachable. You would reach it after the first execution of the loop, if any - but in this very first execution of the loop, you return, thus exiting the function.

For the second part of the question, see [Habib's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12174270/96780).

Answer (score 2):

```
private int GetResult(int start, int end)
{
    int result = 0;
    for (result = start; result < end; result++)
    {
        return result;
    } 
    return result;
}
```

This way the function should work.

Comment: Please Forlan you have declared two times

Comment: -1 no explanation and the result will never increment so the method is useless.

Comment: We don't know what the intended behaviour is.

Comment: @slim: I doubt that it's intended to return always `start`.

Comment: @TimSchmelter We really don't know the intended behaviour. (Darum kannst du nicht sagen das sie nutzlos ist ;-))

Comment: @FrancescoBaruchelli: No, the method does **always** `return start;`

Answer (score 2):

You are calling the for loop.
It sets result=start compares if condition is true
and then returns result.
How shall it ever reach result++ ?
=Unreachable code detected (on result++)

could be that the loop never enters when result > end so
=not all code paths return a value

Answer (score 1):

lets assume that the condition "result < end" is true. The control will then go the statement inside the loop. Since it is a return statement, control will come out of the function/method GetResult. So, the control never reaches to "result++". That is why you get -  unreachable code.

Let me know, if it is useful.

All the best !!!

Answer (score 0):

Because if start >= end, the loop will not be entered

```
private int GetResult(int start, int end)
{
    for (int result = start; result < end; result++)
    {
        return result;
    } 
    return -1; // Path here exists
}
```

Out of interest, if you want to return each of the integers between `start` and `end`, you should look at yield return instead:

```
    private IEnumerable<int> GetResult(int start, int end)
    {
        for (int result = start; result < end; result++)
        {
            yield return result;
        }
        // Now we don't need a return, because the loop will eventually complete
    }
```

**Edit** Looking at the comments, OP may well want a sequence of numbers.

The above method can be iterated

```
foreach (int anInt in GetResult(40, 50))
{
    Console.WriteLine(string.Format("Next value is {0}", anInt));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you add a return statement after the for loop it will compile without errors.

Answer (score 0):

```
private int GetResult(int start, int end)
{
    int result = 0;

    for (result = start; result < end; result++)
    {
        return result;
    } 
    return result;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

This function returns `start` if `start < end`, else it doesn't return anything.

What was the intention of your method ?

Answer (score 0):

Let us consider a scenario in which your condition `result < end` got failed . so the control 
will not enter into loop and will come out of loop. but outside there is no return statement so what would it return as other end is expecting some integer to be return , so that's why you are getting error.

this will work :-

```
private int GetResult(int start, int end)
{
    for (int result = start; result < end; result++)
    {
        return result;
    } 
return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

if the start > end value ,the code inside the loop will never be executed and hence there wont be anything to return from the function and hence you will get those errors.
Moreover there is no point of using for loop as u did since in the first step itself if start

```
private int GetResult(int start, int end)
{   
    if(start<end)
       return start;
    return -1;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think `for` and `return` do what you think they do. As I read your code, it could be dumbed down to this:

```
private int GetResult(int start, int end)
{
    if (start < end)
    {
        return start;
    }
    else
    {
        return 0; // or another default for when start >= end
    }
}
```

Because `return` will, well, return from the method. Since the first iteration of the loop (if start < end) will immediately return `result`, which has been set to the value of `start`.

As your code shows, the `else` part is missing. Therefore the compiler doesn't know what you want to return when start >= end and also result++ is never called because you directly return, so it'll throw the error and warning shown.